# How can I use type-safe unions (variants) inside a class with template functions?

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion, unions, variant

I would like to place a `std::variant` inside a class and return its elements with a template function. Here is an example:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <variant>
class Class {
   public:
    std::variant<std::string, double> cont;
    Class() {}
    template <class V> Class(const V v) { cont = v; }
    template <typename V> V fun() {
        if (std::holds_alternative<double>(cont))
            return std::get<double>(cont);
        else if (std::holds_alternative<std::string>(cont))
            return std::get<std::string>(cont);
    }
};

int main() {
    Class c;
    c = 20;
    double d = c.fun<double>();
    return 0;
}
```

I try to return the elements of the class `Class` through the template function `fun`. However, `gcc-9.1` refuses to compile the code and tells me

```
Class.cpp:12:46: error: cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’ to ‘double’ in return
   12 |             return std::get<std::string>(cont);
```

Why is there any attempt to convert the `string` (the second return type of the function `foo`) to a `double`? Can I prevent this and solve the problem? Do I use the `std::variant` class unidiomatic?

Comment: What do you expect to happen if `c.fun<double>()` is used while `c` actually contains a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that you query the current value stored *at runtime*, while the function signature of the template instantiation is performed *at compile time*. Consider how the member function looks like when you try using it to retrieve a `double`:

```
double fun() {
    if (/* ... */)
        return std::get<double>(cont); // Ok return type is double, too
    else if (/* ... */)
        return std::get<std::string>(cont); // Error, return type should be string?!
}
```

This can't work. You need to change the way to access the data member, e.g. passing an overload set to [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit), by providing two getter-like functions returning `std::optional<double>` and `std::optional<std::string>` or something similar.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed and informative reply. I learned a lot from and can now try to improve the program.

Answer (score 2):

All runtime if branches must be compilable even if not taken. If we call `fun()` with `V == double` then returning an `std::string` makes no sense and causes the error (even if that branch would never be taken, the compiler can't know that for certain).

Instead, just return it right away through `V`:

```
template <typename V> V fun() {
    if (std::holds_alternative<V>(cont))
        return std::get<V>(cont);
    return {}; // return default constructed V. You could throw an exception here instead etc.
}
```